# (Box2dLights) Disable Light for a certain Texture?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, box2dlights

I want add stars on my 2D game, like Terraria-Starbound-Minecraft (School project and hobby).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCGH3.png

Perfect, but when the night comes... The stars are dark!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MbgM.png

I want show the stars without the effects of Box2dLights.
I tried using this code:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    ....
    stage.draw();
    ....
    rayHandler.setCombinedMatrix(stage.getCamera().combined.cpy().scale(Constants.PIXELS_IN_METER, Constants.PIXELS_IN_METER, 5f));
    rayHandler.updateAndRender();
    ....
    stars.draw();
}
```

But...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9zAS.png

I want show the stars without the effects of Box2dLights.

Comment: Stack Overflow is English-only - if you find Spanish easier to understand, you can ask on [es.so] instead. Here, however, posts are required to be in English

Comment: Thanks. So, now I'm searching help in English.

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?

Comment: Hasen, No :...(